# How to convert the following string into object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a string like this

```js
var string = "{
 name: 'something',
  dependencies: [
    'express',
    'axios'
  ]
}"
```

so i want to convert this string into object / json

```js
{
 name: "something",
 dependencies: [
  "express",
  "axios"
 ]
}
```

I tried to do this with `JSON.parse(string)` but it throw Error

```
undefined:2
    dependencies: [
    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 6
```

Comment: That's not valid JS. Please make a [mcve].

Comment: JSON format expects double quotes for strings. This goes for key names as well.

Comment: From a text file

Comment: Instead of trying to convert a string to valid JSON you should fix the code that generates the actual string.

Answer (score 2):

Because your string is not valid JSON.  You'd either need to write a custom parser (or some clunky use of `eval` to use it as JS code directly) or use valid JSON:

```js
var string = `{
  "name": "something",
  "dependencies": [
    "express",
    "axios"
  ]
}`;

console.log(JSON.parse(string));
```

So basically, the ideal approach is to *correct the source of the data* to use JSON.  (Whether that's updating static data, updating code which generates the data, etc. depends on wherever you're getting the data.)

---

Edit: For the "clunky use of `eval`", it might look something like:

```js
var string = `{
  name: 'something',
  dependencies: [
    'express',
    'axios'
  ]
}`;

eval(`var foo = ${string};`);
console.log(foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you can call `JSON.parse`, you will need to replace all single-quotes with double-quotes; and add double-quotes to keys that are missing them.

```js
var original = `{
 name: 'something',
  dependencies: [
    'express',
    'axios'
  ]
}`;

const toObject = (str) => JSON.parse(str
  .replace(/'(\w+)'/g, '"$1"')                 // Replace single -> double
  .replace(/(?<!")\b(\w+)\b(?!")/g, '"$1"'));  // Add double

console.log(toObject(original));
```